# Finding X Value on Quadratic equation with specific rate of change

Tags: algebra-precalculus

In my math class we were given the question:

> Alice, Bob, and Carl are racing. Alice's distance can be modeled as $d=t^2$ where $d$ is distance in meters and $t$ is time in seconds. Bob's speed is modeled as $d=10t$. Carl however is a special situation he can go the speed of either of them, and he can switch, if Alice is going $5$m/s then Carl can go $5$m/s and if Bob is going $10$m/s then so can he. When should Carl use Bob and Alice's speed to win the race in the most optimal time?

Thus far I've been able to get a rough answer of he should switch at $5$ seconds, and it would take him $8.66$ seconds to finish the race, but this has been achieved mostly by guessing and checking. How would I go about solving this algebraically and not having to guess and check?

Thanks So much,
Dobly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The speed of Alice is $2t$ and that of Bob is 10. Bob is initially faster but Alice's speed will match Bob's when $2t=10$. so Carl will travel at 10 m/s for the first 5 seconds then start accelerating so that his instantaneous speed is $2t$. You don't say how long the race is but lets assume 100m. Carl would travel $5*10=50$ meters in the first 5 seconds. After that Carl's distance is given by $d=t^2+25$. So if it is a 100m race then as you deduced, he would win in 8.66 seconds.

Comment: Thanks so much for the response. Could you just explain how you got $2t$ from $d=t^2$.

Comment: Differentiate distances travelled to give speed so $\frac{d (t^2)}{dt}=2t$. Have you done calculus yet? Similarly to get $d=t^2+25$ integrate the velocity $2t$ to get $t^2+const$ and fix constant by $d=50$ when $t=5$.

Comment: Thanks for explaining! Im in Ap Grade 12 math currently and we're learning the foundations of calculus currently, but the teacher doesn't necessarily explain it well